# Subtracting two values

Tags: xml, xslt

i want to subtract two values, should be rather easy I guess but for some reason it's not working.

```
<TD><xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue"/></TD>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="Reduction"/></TD>
<TD><xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue" - "Reduction"/></TD>
```

Comment: You just need to do `<xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue - Reduction"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue" - "Reduction"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="MaxTaxFreeValue - Reduction"/>
```